# A way to set font in Abstract Table Model

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I created a abstract table model that shows data stored. My problem is that the font size is too big for the row height. Is there a way to set font in abstract table model?

Comment: Models shouldn't carry UI information, that's not there job.  The font normally comes via the renderer

Comment: Sorry, had some hardware issues - I did a quick test and you can set the font of the `JTable` directly and if you're using the default renders, they will pick them up.  Alternatively, you could consider changing the `rowHeight` of the `JTable` itself